# Configure NTLM for Opera and Safari and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, opera, ntlm

I am trying to make an existing intranet application that used to work only in IE 7, a browser independent application. In firefox(I set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris) and IE(inbuilt) I was able to configure it. The question is how to configure NTLM in Safari/Opera/Chrome.

Comment: Not too sure about safari / opera but chrome uses system settings and should work the same as IE. Also note, in firefox 4 network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris is removed and doesn't work. (correct me if I'm wrong, but thats what I've found)

Comment: My applications is asp.net web application. I am using C#

Comment: I doubt very much that you will achieve any success tring to use NTLM on Opera. I love Opera, but the single fact that it does not work with NTLM forces me to use Firefox in the company I work. 

The only way I could get Opera pass on this was installing a NTLM proxy application on my client much. I gave up of this approach because Opera was loosing one of if its real strengths: speed. And my hate for IE and Chrome is publicly known, I had to choose the less bad of the browsers, so Firefox won.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox works with below setting:

1. Type about:config in address bar
2. Type ntlm in search and change below value:

   - `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris = .yourdomain.com,localhost`
3. Type negotiate in search and change below values:

   - `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris = .yourdomain.com`
   - `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = .yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Opera in the url bar type about:config then do a search for NTLM